# MIPS, how to get 5 strings from console and then print them out

Tags: string, assembly, mips, qtspim

```
     # Data section
     .data 

insert1:    .word        20     # make space in memory for a word with address insert1              
insert2:    .word        20                 
insert3:    .word        20                 
insert4:    .word        20                 
insert5:    .word        20                     
Input:      .asciiz     "Enter a Series of 5 formulae\n"    
Output:     .asciiz     "The values are:\n"             
CR:     .asciiz     "\n"                    


      # Text Section
     .text 

     .globl my_main


my_main: 

     la $a0, Input
     li $v0, 4 
     syscall        

     la $a0, insert1     # sets $a0 to point to the space allocated for writing a word
     la $a1, insert1     # gets the length of the space in $a1 so we can't go over the memory limit
     li $v0, 8      
     move $t0, $a0      
     syscall        

     la $a0, insert2 
     la $a1, insert2     
     li $v0, 8              
     li $v0, 8      
     move $t1, $a0      
     syscall        

     la $a0, insert3
     la $a1, insert3     
     li $v0, 8      
     li $v0, 8 
     move $t2, $a0
     syscall        

     la $a0, insert4
     la $a1, insert4    
     li $v0, 8              
     li $v0, 8 
     move $t3, $a0
     syscall 

     la $a0, insert5
     la $a1, insert5     
     li $v0, 8      
     li $v0, 8 
     move $t4, $a0
     syscall 

    la $a0, Output 
    li $v0, 4 
    syscall 

    la $a0, insert1 
    li $v0, 4 
    syscall 


    la $a0, insert2 
    li $v0, 4   
    syscall 


    la $a0, insert3 
    li $v0, 4   
    syscall 


    la $a0, insert4 
    li $v0, 4 
    syscall 


    la $a0, insert5 
    li $v0, 4 
    syscall 


    # Exits Program
    li $v0, 10 
    syscall
```

Results I'm getting:

```
Enter a Series of 5 formulae:
hey
man
how
are
you
The values are:
hey
man
how
are
you
man
how
are
you
how 
are 
you
are 
you
you
```

Results I want:

```
Enter a Series of 5 formulae:
hey
man
how
are
you
The values are:
hey 
man
how
are
you
```

So basically I need to take 5 strings from the console and then print out as seen above. Weirdly enough when I use words that are only 1 letter long it prints out correctly but anything else other than single letters returns a sequence of words similar to what I've shown above. I'm new to MIPS and not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

EDIT: It seems I just needed to use .space instead of .word. Thanks to those who commented/answered the question for helping out.

Comment: You probably want `.space 20`. `.word 20` means something completely different.

Comment: `word` in MIPS is machine word, i.e. 32 bit value. Not "word" as human "word". And 32 bits are 4 bytes, and the input service you use will take ASCII strings, where each letter has one byte, so your "hey" string does occupy 4 bytes (full `word`) ("hey" are only 3 letters, but "newline character" of value `10` is included too in the input, check memory view in debugger to see particular bytes), and there's no more space for zero terminator of string, as next string will follow directly after the newline character (in next `word`). If you would enter longer strings, you would see more damage...

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Like I said, new to mips and still learning all the commands. I'll make sure to brush up some more today.